# expose docker container port to eth0

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, elasticsearch, docker

First: could someone with 300 rep make a tag for "docker" please?  TYVM

I'm running a docker container for elasticsearch with the following command:

docker run -d -i -t -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elasticsearch:0.90.5

Which launches correctly and when I curl localhost:9200 I get the elasticsearch json hello world message.

What I can't figure out is how to get the ports to be exposed outside the box.  What I am trying to do is:

docker run -d -i -t -p 123.123.123.123:9200:9200 -p 123.123.123.123:9300:9300 elasticsearch:0.90.5

where 123.123.123.123 is the eth0 IP address.  That does not seem to work.

And now my question:  How do I properly run this container and expose these ports to the outside world?

Here is my "ip addr" from the box which is a headless vmware running ubuntu 12.04.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:52:56:93:78:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 162.248.XXX.XXX/24 brd 162.248.XXX.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 XXX::250:ab00:fe89:78f6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 72:44:60:e8:46:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.1/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global lxcbr0
    inet6 XXX::7080:60ff:fee8:462a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether ba:d6:67:1a:13:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
    inet6 XXX::549c:ebff:fe7d:a22/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
210: vethgVxkby: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master docker0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:d6:67:1a:13:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 XXX::b8d6:67ff:fe1a:13bc/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker might support networking in the future. But for now you can you [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) to manage Docker network like this (Host only).

```
sudo pipework br1 $(docker run -d -i -t elasticsearch:0.90.5) 192.168.2.1/24
sudo ip addr add 192.168.2.254/24 dev br1
```

But if you want it to be public IP address x.x.x.x (ubiquitous):

```
pipework eth0 $(docker run -d -i -t elasticsearch:0.90.5) x.x.x.x
```

Comment: Docker has had network support since March
http://blog.docker.io/2013/03/docker-containers-can-haz-networking-now/

Answer (score 0):

I thought that running it like you did at first `docker run -d -i -t -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 elasticsearch:0.90.5` should work.  Maybe you also have a firewall interfering?

Can you try to run a normal server (ideally elasticsearch without docker, because the elasticsearch config could be a problem too) on port 9200 or whatever first and make sure you can connect to that?  And once thats working I think the original command should work.

Maybe try `sudo ufw allow 9200` or something?